# on view load, start a timer and reveal images at times in iPad app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation

So in my XIB I have a few graphics that need to reveal in order.. say every one second, the next thing will reveal..
I assume I am going to need something involving viewdidload, starting an NSTimer, then animate the revealing of my graphics with the timer. Can anyone please drop me a few ideas, hints or lines of code to get started?

Thanks!

Comment: `a few graphics` does this means images?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Quartz Composer](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/QuartzComposer/qc_intro/qc_intro.html) to build your image sequence, and then render that to a `QCView` or OpenGL context.